# classNotFoundException when using LibGDX controller extension

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been having this issue for about a day now. I have a project that uses the LibGDX controllers extension. This isn't my first time using the extension, and I'm pretty sure I have it set up correctly. However, whenever I call any methods from the Controllers class, the application crashes, saying

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error creating controller manager: com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.desktop.DesktopControllerManager
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/utils/reflect/ClassReflection at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.initialize(Controllers.java:91)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection
```

After googling and reading other people's solutions, the problem seems to come from improperly referencing the gdx-controllers jars. But I'm pretty sure mine is set up right.

This is the core project:
[image]

This is the desktop project:
[image]

The android project is also set up with gdx-controllers.jar and gdx-controllers-android.jar, but I haven't tested it yet.
As far as the actual code goes, the only method I'm calling right now is

```
Controllers.addListener(this);
```

in a class that implements ControllerListener. As soon as I comment that line out, everything runs normally. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you implemented all the methods of ControllerListener?

Comment: Your desktop project should not have gdx-controllers.jar. Only gdx-controllers-desktop.jar and gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar